# Editing a poorly formatted CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, regex, csv

I have this poorly formatted csv file that was converted from a PDF. After some editing i got to this.

```
I-10, New, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT, LDS SS, STYLE: BANGLE", 1.00, 125.00, 1000.00,
I-11, Old, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT; AMT / PER, LDS SS, STYLE:", 1.00, 158.00, 1264.00,
I-12, New, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT; CITRINE, LDS SS, STYLE:", 1.00, 124.00, 992.00,
I-13, New, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT; PERIDOT, LDS SS, STYLE:", 1.00, 173.00, 1384.00,
I-14, New, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT; CITRINE, LDS SS, STYLE:", 1.00, 155.00, 1240.00,
I-15, New, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT; GARNET/CITRINE, LDS SS,", 1.00, 168.00, 1344.00,
I-16, New, "BRACELET JEWELRY 11/28/03, 14KT; AMETH", 1.00, 142.00, 1136.00,
I-19, New, "WEDDING BAND JEWELRY 04/12/94, 14KT; 7 Prin channel .75ctw,", 1.00, 563.00, 2252.00,
I-22, New, "WEDDING BAND JEWELRY 08/14/88, 14KT; 3 ROLLS DIA .88CTW,", 1.00, 528.00, 2112.00,
I-23, New, "SEMI-MOUNT JEWELRY 12/07/92, 14KT; 26 RBC .75CTW, LDS YG", 1.00, 437.50, 1750.00,
I-24, New, "WEDDING BAND JEWELRY 10/14/98, 14KT; 21 PRIN 1.00CTW,", 1.00, 490.00, 2799.00,
I-25, New, "BRIDAL SET JEWELRY 09/09/99, 14KT; 1 OVAL .40CT 10RBC", 1.00, 500.00, 3100.00,
```

The commas within the quotes causes extra columns to be created. So I am trying to make a script to pick the section of the line that is within quotes, remove to commas, and then create and save to a new file.

This is what I have come up with so far, but I haven't used python before.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./INVLISTcopy.csv", sep=',', on_bad_lines='skip')
regex1 = r"([\"\"])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"
srh = re.findall(regex1, df, re.DOTALL)
re.sub(',' ,' ', srh)
df.to_csv('INVLISTcopy1.csv')
```

Comment: can excel open csv correctly?

Comment: Commas within quotes should *not* cause extra columns. They should be considered text. Commas and even newlines are allowed inside quoted fields. This is a perfectly valid CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

try:

```py
import csv

# your output file
output = open('final.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(output)

with open('INVLISTcopy.csv') as csvfile:
    for line in csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
        writer.writerow(line)

output.close()
```

or you can do this with pandas too:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('INVLISTcopy.csv', header=None, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
print(df)
```

It gives you this:

[image: CSV Output]